# How to programmatically clear the entry field in an iMessage extension?

Tags: ios, swift, sms, imessage, imessage-extension

Ok, I have looked everywhere and can't find a single post on this. I am building an iMessage extension app and I need to know IF and how there is a way to programmatically clear the iMessage text entry field. Not necessarily edit the content, just delete all text/stickers that have been put there.

I mean here not once the message is sent:

[image]

I know we have all these, and I use the last two to see if a sticker has been sent or it has been cancelled within the input field.

```
override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when the extension is about to move from the inactive to active state.
        // This will happen when the extension is about to present UI.

        // Use this method to configure the extension and restore previously stored state.
    }

    override func didResignActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when the extension is about to move from the active to inactive state.
        // This will happen when the user dissmises the extension, changes to a different
        // conversation or quits Messages.

        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers,
        // and store enough state information to restore your extension to its current state
        // in case it is terminated later.
    }

    override func didReceive(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when a message arrives that was generated by another instance of this
        // extension on a remote device.

        // Use this method to trigger UI updates in response to the message.
    }

    override func didStartSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when the user taps the send button.
        print("sent icon")
    }

    override func didCancelSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when the user deletes the message without sending it.

        // Use this to clean up state related to the deleted message.
        print("nope, icon not sent")
    }
```

How can I do this, or anything similaR?

Comment: As far as I know, you can not. In the state you show (keyboard & text) your extension is inactive/killed). Independent of iMessage Extensions, you can write a custom keyboard though.

Comment: No, I meant if my message app were running, i.e. they had selected one of my stickers and it was sitting in the input field with my app open

Comment: @skyguy Did you find the answer to your question or found workaround.